# change multiple dataframe columns based on list of users

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Let's say I have this dataframe in pandas:

```py
data = {'user':['Apple', 'One', 'Tom'], 
        'col_1':[1, 2, 3],
        'col_2':[4, 5, 6],
        'col_3':[7, 8, 9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which outputs:

| user | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| One | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| Tom | 7 | 8 | 9 |

Now, here is the deal: **I want to modify the value of columns `col_1`, `col_2` and `col_3` if the user is within a specific list of users. Otherwise, I have to keep the current value of the columns.**

### My proposal:

First, I created a dictionary, where the keys show the users that need modifications. Also, for each user, I created a list of the new values (`col_1`, `col_2` and `col_3`, respectively) This way:

```py
my_dict = {
    'one'  : ['col_1_value_one', 'col_2_value_one', 'col_3_value_one'],
    'two'  : ['col_1_value_two', 'col_2_value_two', 'col_3_value_two'],
    'apple': ['col_1_value_apple', 'col_2_value_apple', 'col_3_value_apple']
}
```

Then, I created a list based on the dict keys:

```py
list_users = list(my_dict.keys())
```

Finally, I was able to verify whether the user was in fact within the list of keys or not by using `np.where`, `contains`and some regex (*that is why I joined the list with "|"* and used `lower()`). It works properly when keeping the "old" value if the user is not present in the list.

```py
df['col_1'] = np.where(df['user'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(list_users), na=False, regex=True), 
                                        "<I need to replace this!>", 
                                        df['col_1'])
df['col_2'] = np.where(df['user'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(list_users), na=False, regex=True), 
                                        "<I need to replace this!>", 
                                        df['col_2'])
df['col_3'] = np.where(df['user'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(list_users), na=False, regex=True), 
                                        "<I need to replace this!>", 
                                        df['col_3'])
```

However, as you can see I couldn't find a way to replace the values for the ones present in the dictionary values if the user is in fact within the list. For example, if the user is *"Apple"*, then the new values for `col_1`, `col_2` and `col_3` are:

- col_1_value_apple
- col_2_value_apple
- col_3_value_apple

Expected output based on example:

| user | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | col_1_value_apple | col_2_value_apple | col_3_value_apple |
| One | col_1_value_one | col_2_value_one | col_3_value_one |
| Tom | 7 | 8 | 9 |

Here, both *"Apple"* and *"One"* users are modified, whilst *"Tom"* is not in the list, therefore keeping their original values.

I am sure this is not the optimal way to solve this, but any help would be highly appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```py
for name, cols in my_dict.items():
    df.loc[df['user'].str.lower() == name, ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']] = cols
```